# Extracting number of unique observations using a string

Tags: r, unique

I have a column like this:

```
data.frame(x = c("ABC1","ABD1","ABE1","ABF1","ABG1","ABC2","ABC2","ABF2","ABE2"))
```

I want to find out how many unique observations there are which contain "AB" and a letter. So ABC1 and ABC2 are not unique but ABC1 and ABD1 are.

In this example, there would be 5 unique observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only the first 3 characters for each word. Then count the number of unique occurrences.

```
df = data.frame(x = c("ABC1","ABD1","ABE1","ABF1","ABG1","ABC2","ABC2","ABF2","ABE2"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

length(unique(substr(df$x,1,3)))
5
```

Comment: You don't need `sapply` to use `substr` here...`substr` is already vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

Since only the third character determines the uniqueness, we remove characters on all other positions to see the number of unique leftovers:

```
length(unique(gsub("[(AB)0-9]","",df$x)))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and what it is doing.